# Why isn't all my storage listed in settings?

Tags: internal-storage, 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

[image]
[image]

As seen in the above images, internal storage uses way more then by adding Apps and Cached data to each other. This could be the Android OS, but I think it isn't bequase on the first picture it is deprecated from the other entries. What could be possibly using the unlisted usage and can I reclaim that space (by moving it to my adapted SD)?

Comment: The first screenshot seems to show available *partitions:* "Android OS" corresponds to `/system`, "Internal storage" to `/data` and the last one to your external SD card. This is why Android is mentioned explicitly here. Still I agree the second screenshot looks incomplete: usually it also lists media files (music, video) at least, no idea why that's omitted here. I assume tapping the top entry simply launches some file explorer?

Comment: @Izzy Tapping the top entry (The big total usage one, right?) doesn't do anything on both screens.

Comment: Yeah, that one. Irritating. Anything related when you open the overflow menu (the 3 "stapled dots" in the second screenshot)?

Comment: It only shows "Migrate data". Pressing that option opens a window called "Move data now" which has the text "The move takes about 8 seconds. It wil free 83.25 MB on SD Card." I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: No. That sound as if you're using "adoptable storage" (i.e. using your external SD card as internal storage), and this would migrate your data "back" to the real internal storage so you could revert the adoption. OK, not sure why the other details are not shown; so you'd possible need a 3rd party tool to investigate that. You can find some candidates in my app list on [Storage Analysis](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_storageanalysis).

Answer (score -1):

If you have large apps, then the ***total*** size of the app is not displayed: The extra files which the app needs in order to run itself, do not show up in the description of storage. That means the total size of your apps might be greater than 1.40 GB. This might be one of the possible reasons.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This unfortunately doesn't answer the question "What could be possibly using the unlisted usage and can I reclaim that space (by moving it to my adapted SD)?" Also I'm not sure about your statement. Do you have some backing for it? Why should sizes of large apps not be displayed?

Comment: The extra files which the app needs in order to run itself, do not show up in the description of storage. That is why the depicted app sizes are lesser than the actual size required.

Comment: Why shouldn't they show up at all? They should be shown either as "app data" or at least as "others". Backing: See [this screenshot](http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/212469-image/How-to-install-Android-6.0-Marshmallow-factory-images-on-a-Google-Nexus-device.jpg) and also [this one](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/euf/assets/images/faqs/Marshmallow/sd-card/sd-7.PNG). Note the difference?